# TableSorter : Filter digits with comma as decimal sign

Tags: tablesorter

With jQuery TableSorter, I can't filter a column correctly that contains European formatted digits (dot every 3 digit and comma as decimal sign). Anyway, sorting work like a charm.

See my problem here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ted22/9tBgZ/13/

I work with this piece of code :

```
jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "commaDigit",
    is: function(s, table) {
        var c = table.config;
        return $.tablesorter.isDigit(s.replace(/[,.]/g, ""), c);
    },
    format: function(s) {
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/[,.]/g, ""));
    },
    parsed: false,
    type: "numeric"
});
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks in adavance !

Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the [`usNumberFormat` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#usnumberformat) to `false` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/9tBgZ/16/))

Comment: It's so easy ! Thanks again Mottie !